# Crypto provider in JDK

Tags: java, cryptography

Is it correctly understood that in order to do cryptography in Java using eg. `Cipher`, I must choose an external provider to setup, that is, the JDK does not come with and contains a "default" provider ?

Comment: easily answered yourself with trivial experimentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the Java version you have. Since Java 1.4, JCE is included by default with a default provider stack available. Check out your default providers at `{$JRE_HOME}/lib/security/java.policy`. You'll see something like

> List of providers and their preference orders (see above):
>    security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun security.provider.2=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
>   security.provider.3=sun.security.ec.SunEC
>   security.provider.4=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
>   security.provider.5=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
>   security.provider.6=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
>   security.provider.7=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
>   security.provider.8=org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
>   security.provider.9=sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC
>   security.provider.10=sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI

which represents the default provider stack (order is important here).

Comment: Java 1.4 was released in 2002, so unless you happen to use very outdated software, you will have the default providers installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can check a default algorithm for SSL/TLS handshake and change it if you need.
See file `{$JRE_HOME}/lib/security/java.policy`:

```
ssl.KeyManagerFactory.algorithm=SunX509
ssl.TrustManagerFactory.algorithm=PKIX
```